# Pipe Stream Question

Tags: c, file, stream, pipe, execution

I am trying to execute a program I created in popen and then collect the output. The program I execute takes 30 seconds (there are 30 sleep(1)s) and after each seconds it sends chunks of output. What puzzles me is that when I call `pipe = popen("test -flag", "r")` it finishes immediately and the FILE stream pipe is empty. Are my assumptions that that the program will halt and wait for test to finish executing before continuing or does it initiate the order to collect the output and immediately continue on? If it is the latter, is there any way to pause the program until the pipe has all the output before continuing?

Thanks!

Comment: I bet you're getting `/bin/test` instead of `./test`.

Comment: well actually my program is "test1" located in "/tmp/mytestfolder/test1". Take test as just a general exe file

Comment: Try substituting something known to work like `/bin/ls /`. That'll help you figure out if the problem is in the calling program or the called one.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `popen()` is supposed to be relatively quick, so your program can get on with reading the output from the program.  Certainly, `popen()` itself does not wait for the invoked program to finish.  Once the `popen()` returns, your program should be able to read from the file stream; it will hang until there is input waiting, or until the other process closes the pipe (e.g. terminates), at which point it will get an EOF indication.  You can then `pclose()` the stream you were reading from.

How does your test program behave when you run it directly with its output sent to a pipe?  Note that standard I/O typically behaves differently when the output is a pipe (full buffering) as against a terminal (line buffering).

Comment: it preforms a math equation like 20000 times (yet without sleep it executes in less than a 5 secs). Could I stall caller of popen for a bit?

Comment: @Chris: you can call `sleep(30);` to make it hold up for 30 seconds if you want to.  However, a pipe has only a finite (and fairly small) capacity - typically about 5 KiB - so you need your reading process to read before the pipe is full; otherwise, the other process will block, waiting for your main process to do some reading.  Your main process would hang until there is input to read if it simply reads from the file stream returned by `popen()`, of course.

Comment: wow I think I'm an idiot :P. I think I opened the file but did input the step that extract chunk from the file into the string. So probably the reason I am not getting and output is because it referencing a blank string. Imma modify my code. I'll get back to you in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Read `pipe` until `EOF` is returned.

Comment: nope that was my bad guys. I fixed it and I am shamed :( for such a stupid question. Thanks for the help however.